# Javascript import all modules from a file as a global variables

Tags: javascript

In script1.js, I have the following exports:

```
export function test1() {
  // do something
}

export function test2() {
  // do something
}
```

I am importing script1.js into script2.js:

```
import * as functions from './script1.js';

functions.test1();
functions.test2();
```

I am wondering if there is a way to import all the modules from script1.js, and directly place them inside the global variables of script2.js. So I can directly access them with test1(), test2(), without the intermediate step of putting them in an object.

I know that we can do `import {test1, test2} from './script1.js';`, but if I have a lot of exports, then the deconstruction will be tedious.

In another word, what I am looking for is something equivalent of:

```
import * from './script1.js';

test1();
test2();
```

The above code block is hypothetical, and it does not work.

Comment: `import './script1'` should do it

Comment: A terrible solution for a similar problem: If `with` was permitted in strict mode, you could do `with (functions) {` but luckily, modules are required to be strict.

Comment: Just tried, `import './script1' ` yields error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given your current code, it's not possible. The whole point of modules is to **avoid implicit global pollution**. To do something like this, you'd have to explicitly assign the functions to the global object inside the module, eg, change:

```
export function test1() {
  // do something
}
```

to

```
window.test1 = function test1() {
  // do something
};
```

and then, when the module is imported, the functions will be available globally:

```
import './script1.js';
```

But this is an antipattern:

> but if I have a lot of exports, then the desconstruction will be tedious.

It does require some boilerplate, but don't be afraid of it - in larger projects, having explicit dependency chains is a *huge plus* for maintainability. It also permits tree-shaking, which isn't possible for modules with side-effects only (like assigning to the global object).

Answer (score 2):

you can also very simply auto generate the import , with a script like this:

```
import * as functions from './script1.js';

const function_names = Object.keys(functions).join(',')

console.log( function_names ) //output: test1,test2
```

your list is ready in your console!

Comment: That's bloody creative mate. Nice way to use a sort of Reflection to help generate your import. I think what's missing from your answer for the google-coder generation is to understand that this trick is to create a list in the log that you copy-and-paste to use as the import {.....} from "..." statement in your main.js file (or wherever).

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
import * as S1 from './script1.js'
globalThis.S1 = S1
```

then use your functions as

```
S1.test1()
S1.test2()
```